# Binding XLS files while gettind rid of extra sheets

Tags: r, excel, rbind, readxl

I have 774 XLS files that I would like to merge into one big CSV data-base. They are roughly similar, but I don't know how to handle the differences...

Some XLS files have more than one sheet, and they are useless; thus I need to get rid of them. The problem is that, in some files, these extra sheets were moved to be the first, while in others this doesn't happen. So I can't depend of the default value of functions that read XLS on R, right?

Besides that, the name of the extra sheets (those I don't intend to keep) may vary.

Below I present the script that I know, hoping someone could help me adapt it to this situation.

```
setwd("D:/Folder")
library(readxl)
lst = list.files()
df = data.frame()

# Now comes the loop

for(table in lst){
  dataFromExcel <- read_excel(table)
  df <- rbind(df,dataFromExcel)
}
```

When I run the loop, I receive the message:

> New names:
>
> - `` -> ...3
> - `` -> ...4
> - `` -> ...5
>   Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Can someone give me some help?

Comment: Thet  `` -> ..3 lines are for  columns without names. This is a warning, not a breaking error. fotr the POSIX-related error: try reading all the data as character by setting the `col_types`-argumekt like so: `readxl::read|_excel( yourfilenamehere, col_types = "text")`..

Comment: This is weird, because technically every column in the sheet I want to extract the data has names in [their first row](https://imgur.com/CD3qHMV). In the **other** sheet, the one I do not want to extract any data, I might see columns without names.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for(table in lst){
  dataFromExcel <- read_excel(table, col_types = "text" ) # <- !!
  df <- rbind(df,dataFromExcel)
}
```

you will have to wrangle the data to the correct type afterwards..

further: perhaps a more R-like code:

```
library( data.table )
DT <- rbindlist( lapply( list, read_excel, col_types = "text" ), 
                 use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
```

should do the same as your for-loop (and has some nice extra features, see ?data.table::rbindlist ).

Comment: Program returned this:

`New names:
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  números de colunas dos argumentos não correspondem`

This last sentence is in Portguese, which means " _column numbers of the arguments do not match_ "